# Android phone as USB Keyboard/HID-Gadget/

Tags: android, hid, usb-otg

I'm looking for a possibility to use Android Smartphones as a USB-Keyboard, same as I would be using Linux Gadget and a raspberry pi with OTG port. 
So I imagine it like this:

1. Connect Android phone to some computer via standard USB.
2. Start my App on the phone.
3. Computer identifies the phone as a basic keyboard (no need to install drivers or the like)
4. From my App I can send text to the computer so for the computer it seems that the text is typed by the keyboard.

Is there some possibility to build an App like this without modifying the Android Kernel or rooting the phone.

Thank you

Comment: i am looking for exactly the same thing! there is one answer here that says it ought to be possible: https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/176frr/android_phone_as_wired_usb_keyboardmouse/c82setm/ but i didn't find any code yet